# INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm making a Ticketing System using MVC Entity Framework 5.

How my classes are mapped:

User to Admin is 1 to 0..1  (I can assign some users with admin status but I don't want every user to have it)

Admin to Ticket is 1 to 1 (You can only assign 1 admin(to fix the issue) to a ticket)

User to Ticket is 1 to many (One user can create multiple tickets)

I'm having this issue where if I create a ticket with a user that doesn't have an adminID (Look in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2FzA.png)) It'll give me the following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Ticket_dbo.Administrator_UserID". The conflict occurred in
>   database "RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext", table
>   "dbo.Administrator", column 'UserID'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

I think the issue is because of the mapping between "Admin to Tickets". The 1 to 1  relationship forces the condition where if i create a ticket the user must have "adminID" or there's a conflict in the database.

My question is that what mapping should Admin to Tickets be to fix this issue?
Maybe 1 to 0..*(1 to 1 or many) would it fix the issue?

Administrator

```
public class Administrator
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Key]
    *public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }* 
}
```

Ticket.cs

```
public enum Priority
{
    Low, Med, High
}

public class Ticket
{
    public int TicketID { get; set; }
    public string Issue { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Priority")]
    public Priority? Priority { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }


    *public int AdminID { get; set; }*
}
```

Applied Andy's solution where I made Admin to Ticket a 1:Many relationship
(Added `public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }` in the Ticket.cs)

[Error LOOK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhC16.png)

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Ticket_dbo.Administrator_UserID". The conflict occurred in
>   database "RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext", table
>   "dbo.Administrator", column 'UserID'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Administrator

```
public class Administrator
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Key]
    *public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }* 
}

public class Ticket
{
    public int TicketID { get; set; }
    public string Issue { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Priority")]
    public Priority? Priority { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }


    *public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }*
}
```

Comment: Ticket to Admin 1:1 - only one admin can work on a ticket, Admin to Ticket 1:many - an admin can be assigned to multiple tickets.

Comment: Someone suggested me to make adminID a nullable int `int?`. Would it have the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

Your adminID property of Ticket cannot accept nullable int, therefore it must have an admin. I'm guessing you don't want that required in the beginning, it gets assigned later? Should be `int?`.

Comment: What "required in the beginning" are you talking about? So i just go `public int AdminID { get; set; }` in the Administrator.cs and Ticket.cs?? I"m just wondering because @Kevin said that I should change the relationship to 1:many so an admin can be assigned to multiple tickets. Would your solution also work like that?

Comment: When you create a ticket, you don't know the admin at that time? Some time later, an admin is assigned to the ticket? If so, AdminId should be null until it's assigned. If the admin is assigned at the creation of the ticket, that's a different story.

Comment: So I re edited the code in the question and it is suppose to so a 1(admin) to many relationship(ticket) . Source: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/28/mvcscaffolding-one-to-many-relationships/ but it gives me the error in image 2(Look in question).

Comment: Why is Administrator a separate class? Why not inherit from User, or just have UserType on the User class? Seems redundant as is.

The error is indicating that you're trying to set the UserId for an Administrator, and the UserId doesn't exist. It's not really Ticket related.

Comment: @In the future I want Users with administrator status to be able to access more links on the website than normal users. I'm not sure if I can do that if I follow your solution.

Comment: If user.UserType == UserType.Admin